# Displaying data in a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following function that fetches all data rows from a db table.
All seems fine except one part that I am not sure about assigning fetched `$row` to `$data` in my code. 
As I have not explicitly set fetch mode, I expect an array object to be returned from a call to `fetch()`.

```
function getAll()
{  
    $data = array();

    try
    {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo', 'root', '');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM pdo_table');
        $stmt->execute();

        while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            $data = $row;
        }
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $data;   
}
```

Now, I have a separate **index** page that echo the returned `$data` in a html table.
I first added a reference to the php page that contains the function in question, then assigned the returned array to another variable called `$results`.

```
<?php foreach($results as $row) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Date'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['company'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['interest'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>             
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

I only have one row inserted at the moment but this does not populate result in a table as desired
[image]

Comment: expecting `$data = $row;` to be `$data[] = $row;`

Comment: @Akam Nice catch please post this as answer with some detials

Comment: I have already declared as `$data = array()`, do I need to make it as you suggested in the loop as well?

Comment: adding `[]` solved it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although your aim is right, there are TOO MAY a flaws with implementation.

A proper code:

```
function getAll($conn, $sql, $data = $array())
{  
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
```

You **should not connect** in this function but use site-wide connection established **once**
This function should be able accept an arbitrary query, as well as bound data for it
And your idea of catching exceptions is wrong.

Answer (score -3):

change only one statement

```
          $stmt->execute(); to


     $result=   $stmt->query($statement); 
        to fetch data
         and   process  result set in following way
    while($row=$result->fetch())
        {
      <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Date'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['company'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['phone'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['interest'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['message'] ?></td>             
</tr>
```

}

vote me sure  thanks

Comment: "Vote [you]"? Sure! -1